# Force one program to use VPN connection, not all

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I would like to do the opposite of this:
[Exempt programs or domain from VPN connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26870/exempt-programs-or-domain-from-vpn-connection)

Where just one program is forced thru an OpenVPN connection.  Is there a way?

Comment: Please try `openvpn --help` or `man openvpn`. I can only look on Wednesday but I will try help you if you can't find what you're looking for.

Comment: Please look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146463/use-openvpn-only-for-one-application-service) as well.

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751003/70524